# R Shiny - No initial value selected in radioButtons?

Tags: r, radio-button, shiny

From the documentation:

> radioButtons(inputId, label, choices, selected = NULL, inline = FALSE,
>     width = NULL)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *selected*    The initially selected value (if not specified then defaults to the first value)

But, can you specify the `selected` argument so that the rendered radioButtons has no initial value selected? The output of this initial value could be an empty string (`""`). In the example below, neither "a" nor "b" should be selected when the app is run.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        radioButtons("test","test",choices=c("a","b"),selected = NULL),
        verbatimTextOutput("value")
      )
    ), server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
      output$value <- renderText(input$test)
    })
  )
)
```

**UPDATE**

As sugested by Hackerman, `selected = character(0)` does the trick.

Comment: Ok, when you run that code, what happens?

Comment: When I run it, the "a" button (the first value) is already selected. I would like no button to be selected.

Comment: You can use `selected = character(0)` instead of `selected = NULL`

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem with `selected` is that if not specified then defaults to the first value. But you can workaround this using the following:

```
selected = character(0)
```

Another way is providing a default option, like `Nothing Selected`

```
radioButtons("test","test",choices=c("Nothing Selected"="","a"="a","b"="b"),selected = NULL),
```

Comment: The `selected = character(0)` alternative is simple but it does seem like a hack. I worry that it might have secondary effects (although I can't think of any now).

Comment: The closes effect which I could think of is, once the user makes the selection then there is no way by which the user can go back to the initial stage i.e when no radio button was selected. To counter this may be add an extra radio button saying 'None selected'

Comment: Note that this does not work with `awesomeRadio` from shinyWidgets (although it does work with `radioButtons` as stated)

Comment: @nico Yes, this is an almost 4 years old answer...I've been a little bit far away from R development during those years :)

Comment: Oh yes, but your answer was still useful!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want an initial value because it would be observed, there seem to be 3 solutions:

- use an extra option, e.g. called 'none' see radioButtons help
- use character(0) (see radioButtons help)
- use an extra actionButton ond observe that button in stead.

If you do not want to blur your user interface with an extra radioButtons choice or actionButton, use character(0).

However when using 'character(0)' you may have to resolve a side effect as well. The problem is that 'character(0)' will **not** reset the input parameter to NULL, so you can't use the same option twice (which may or may not be desirable).This is shown in the following sample program.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = c ('a', 'b', 'c'), selected=character(0)) })
n  <- 0
observe({
    actionId <- input$actionId
    n <<- n+1
    if (!is.null(actionId)) {
        if (actionId=='a')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action A"))
        if (actionId=='b')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action B"))
        if (actionId=='c')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action C"))
        output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = c ('a', 'b', 'c'), selected=character(0)) })
    } else                  output$action  <- renderText ("actionId equals NULL")
}) } 
ui <- fluidPage (
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel ( uiOutput('uiRadioButtons')),
        mainPanel    (uiOutput('action'))
    ) ) 
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

This can be resolved (though it may be too slow for remote applications) by using and observing a dummy radioButtons as follows.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
showActions <- function() {
    output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI ({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = c ('a', 'b', 'c'), selected=character(0)) })
}
showActions()
n  <- 0
observe({
    actionId <- input$actionId
    n <<- n+1
    if (!is.null(actionId)) {
        if (actionId=='dummy')  showActions ()
        else {
            if (actionId=='a')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action A"))
            if (actionId=='b')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action B"))
            if (actionId=='c')  output$action  <- renderText (paste (n, "action C"))
            output$uiRadioButtons <- renderUI({ radioButtons (inputId='actionId', label='action:', choices = 'dummy') })
        }
    } else                  output$action  <- renderText ("actionId equals NULL")

})
}
ui <- fluidPage (
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel (
            # radioButtons (inputId='objectId', label='selct object:', choices = c ('o1', 'o2', 'o3'), inline = TRUE),
            uiOutput('uiRadioButtons')
        ),
        mainPanel    (uiOutput('action'))
    )
)
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

It looks ugly, but it works and I would pleased, if some could show me a better solution, e.g. a way to reset the input variable to NULL.