# How to filter out answer options on previous answers

Tags: r, shiny, set-difference

I am creating a shiny app. I have a first multiple choice question q1 with a possible list of answers. In the second, one-choice question q2, as a list of possible answers I have the options selected in q1 (and until here everything works ok). In q3, as a list of possible answers I am trying to have the ones selected in q1 minus the ones selected in q2 (input$q1 - input$q2). Then I have q4 where i want as possible answers input$q1 - input$q2 - input$q3, and so on.

So for example, if the answers to q1 are "a","b","c", "d" then, as a list of possible answers in q2 I will have the same ( a","b","c", "d"). If in q2 I answer "a", as a list of possible answers for q3 I want to have "b", "c", "d". If in q3 I answer "b", then the options for q4 should be "c","d". And so on.

Here is a simplified code with the issue, as it is now it gives the error "Error in [[: subscript out of bounds":

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


v1<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")


ui<- fluidPage(
  
pickerInput("q1", "", choices = v1, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),

radioButtons("q2", "", choices = c("0"), selected = NULL),

radioButtons("q3", "", choices = c("0"), selected = NULL),

radioButtons("q4", "", choices = c("0"), selected = NULL)

)

server<-function(input, output, session) {
 v2<-reactive({
   input$q1
 })
  
   observeEvent(v2(), {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q2",
      choices = v2()
    )
  })
   
  v3<-reactive({
    input$q1[input$q1 !=input$q2]
  })
   
  
  observeEvent(v3(), {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q3",
      choices = v3()
    )
  })
  
  v4<-reactive({
    input$q1[input$q1 !=input$q2 & input$q1 !=input$q3]
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(v4(), {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q4",
      choices = v4()
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also tried with `setdiff()` with this code. This is problematic because it does not update if the answer in q1 is changed and I wouldn't be sure on how to do when I add the 4th question.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("q1", "", choices = v1, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  radioButtons("q2", "", choices = c("0"), selected = NULL),
  radioButtons("q3", "", choices = c("0"), selected = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v2 <- reactive({
    input$q1
  })
  
  observeEvent(v2(), {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q2",
      choices = v2()
    )
  })

  v3<-reactive({
c(input$q1, input$q2
)  })
  
  observeEvent(v3, {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q3",
      choices = setdiff(input$q1, input$q2)
    )
  })
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you to anyone that can help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selectInput that is dependent on another selectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929206/selectinput-that-is-dependent-on-another-selectinput)

Comment: @Limey Not really. My problem here  is with the specific terminology to be used to remove the chosen second answer from the answer option list for the third answer. The dependency between the second answer and the first one works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs due to initializing the radio buttons with `selected = NULL` instead of `selected = character(0)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535980/r-shiny-no-initial-value-selected-in-radiobuttons) for details.

With `selected = NULL` the input variables are non-empty from the get-go, which leads to a calculation where the choices are calculated as `character(0)` and then this happens:

```
> radioButtons("q3","",choices = character(0),selected = NULL)
## Error in args$choiceValues[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

This should work (and I shortened the code a bit):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

v1<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

ui<- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("q1", "", choices = v1, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  radioButtons("q2", "", choices = c("0"), selected = character(0)),
  radioButtons("q3", "", choices = c("0"), selected = character(0)),
  radioButtons("q4", "", choices = c("0"), selected = character(0))
)

server<-function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$q1, {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q2",
      choices = input$q1,
      selected = character(0)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$q2, {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q3",
      choices = input$q1[input$q1 !=input$q2],
      selected = character(0)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$q3, {
    updateRadioButtons(
      session,
      "q4",
      choices = input$q1[input$q1 !=input$q2 & input$q1 !=input$q3],
      selected = character(0)
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Oh right! This works exactly as I wished, thank so much!